# Is there a list of (all the) Suttas that mention supranormal powers?

Tags: sutras, psychic-powers

I know there are the miracles of the historical Buddha and the Samannaphala Sutta, but is there a comprehensive list of Suttas that mention supranormal power(s)?

Answer (score 2):

Here are the search results for "psychic" in five main nikayas. It is not exhaustive since translation is not complete:

- [AN10.90](https://suttacentral.net/an10.90/en/sujato)
- [AN10.97](https://suttacentral.net/an10.97/en/sujato)
- [AN11.10](https://suttacentral.net/an11.10/en/sujato)
- [AN1.188-197](https://suttacentral.net/an1.188-197/en/sujato)
- [AN1.235-247](https://suttacentral.net/an1.235-247/en/sujato)
- [AN1.394-574](https://suttacentral.net/an1.394-574/en/sujato)
- [AN3.101](https://suttacentral.net/an3.101/en/sujato)
- [AN3.102](https://suttacentral.net/an3.102/en/sujato)
- [AN3.144](https://suttacentral.net/an3.144/en/sujato)
- [AN3.156-162](https://suttacentral.net/an3.156-162/en/sujato)
- [AN3.40](https://suttacentral.net/an3.40/en/sujato)
- [AN3.60](https://suttacentral.net/an3.60/en/sujato)
- [AN4.191](https://suttacentral.net/an4.191/en/sujato)
- [AN4.276](https://suttacentral.net/an4.276/en/sujato)
- [AN4.45](https://suttacentral.net/an4.45/en/sujato)
- [AN5.100](https://suttacentral.net/an5.100/en/sujato)
- [AN5.23](https://suttacentral.net/an5.23/en/sujato)
- [AN5.28](https://suttacentral.net/an5.28/en/sujato)
- [AN5.67](https://suttacentral.net/an5.67/en/sujato)
- [AN5.68](https://suttacentral.net/an5.68/en/sujato)
- [AN6.2](https://suttacentral.net/an6.2/en/sujato)
- [AN6.41](https://suttacentral.net/an6.41/en/sujato)
- [AN6.54](https://suttacentral.net/an6.54/en/sujato)
- [AN6.70](https://suttacentral.net/an6.70/en/sujato)
- [AN7.71](https://suttacentral.net/an7.71/en/sujato)
- [AN8.19](https://suttacentral.net/an8.19/en/sujato)
- [AN8.28](https://suttacentral.net/an8.28/en/sujato)
- [AN8.30](https://suttacentral.net/an8.30/en/sujato)
- [AN8.70](https://suttacentral.net/an8.70/en/sujato)
- [AN9.35](https://suttacentral.net/an9.35/en/sujato)
- [AN9.83](https://suttacentral.net/an9.83/en/sujato)
- [AN9.84-91](https://suttacentral.net/an9.84-91/en/sujato)
- [AN9.92](https://suttacentral.net/an9.92/en/sujato)
- [DN10](https://suttacentral.net/dn10/en/sujato)
- [DN11](https://suttacentral.net/dn11/en/sujato)
- [DN14](https://suttacentral.net/dn14/en/sujato)
- [DN16](https://suttacentral.net/dn16/en/sujato)
- [DN17](https://suttacentral.net/dn17/en/sujato)
- [DN18](https://suttacentral.net/dn18/en/sujato)
- [DN24](https://suttacentral.net/dn24/en/sujato)
- [DN26](https://suttacentral.net/dn26/en/sujato)
- [DN28](https://suttacentral.net/dn28/en/sujato)
- [DN29](https://suttacentral.net/dn29/en/sujato)
- [DN2](https://suttacentral.net/dn2/en/sujato)
- [DN30](https://suttacentral.net/dn30/en/sujato)
- [DN33](https://suttacentral.net/dn33/en/sujato)
- [DN34](https://suttacentral.net/dn34/en/sujato)
- [DN3](https://suttacentral.net/dn3/en/sujato)
- [MN103](https://suttacentral.net/mn103/en/sujato)
- [MN104](https://suttacentral.net/mn104/en/sujato)
- [MN108](https://suttacentral.net/mn108/en/sujato)
- [MN118](https://suttacentral.net/mn118/en/sujato)
- [MN119](https://suttacentral.net/mn119/en/sujato)
- [MN129](https://suttacentral.net/mn129/en/sujato)
- [MN12](https://suttacentral.net/mn12/en/sujato)
- [MN149](https://suttacentral.net/mn149/en/sujato)
- [MN151](https://suttacentral.net/mn151/en/sujato)
- [MN16](https://suttacentral.net/mn16/en/sujato)
- [MN25](https://suttacentral.net/mn25/en/sujato)
- [MN37](https://suttacentral.net/mn37/en/sujato)
- [MN49](https://suttacentral.net/mn49/en/sujato)
- [MN50](https://suttacentral.net/mn50/en/sujato)
- [MN56](https://suttacentral.net/mn56/en/sujato)
- [MN6](https://suttacentral.net/mn6/en/sujato)
- [MN73](https://suttacentral.net/mn73/en/sujato)
- [MN77](https://suttacentral.net/mn77/en/sujato)
- [MN86](https://suttacentral.net/mn86/en/sujato)
- [MN91](https://suttacentral.net/mn91/en/sujato)
- [MN92](https://suttacentral.net/mn92/en/sujato)
- [MN99](https://suttacentral.net/mn99/en/sujato)
- [SN12.70](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.70/en/sujato)
- [SN14.15](https://suttacentral.net/sn14.15/en/sujato)
- [SN16.9](https://suttacentral.net/sn16.9/en/sujato)
- [SN21.1](https://suttacentral.net/sn21.1/en/sujato)
- [SN21.3](https://suttacentral.net/sn21.3/en/sujato)
- [SN22.101](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.101/en/sujato)
- [SN2.26](https://suttacentral.net/sn2.26/en/sujato)
- [SN22.80](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.80/en/sujato)
- [SN22.81](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.81/en/sujato)
- [SN40.1](https://suttacentral.net/sn40.1/en/sujato)
- [SN40.2](https://suttacentral.net/sn40.2/en/sujato)
- [SN40.3](https://suttacentral.net/sn40.3/en/sujato)
- [SN40.4](https://suttacentral.net/sn40.4/en/sujato)
- [SN40.5](https://suttacentral.net/sn40.5/en/sujato)
- [SN40.6](https://suttacentral.net/sn40.6/en/sujato)
- [SN40.7](https://suttacentral.net/sn40.7/en/sujato)
- [SN40.8](https://suttacentral.net/sn40.8/en/sujato)
- [SN40.9](https://suttacentral.net/sn40.9/en/sujato)
- [SN41.4](https://suttacentral.net/sn41.4/en/sujato)
- [SN4.20](https://suttacentral.net/sn4.20/en/sujato)
- [SN43.12](https://suttacentral.net/sn43.12/en/sujato)
- [SN43.7](https://suttacentral.net/sn43.7/en/sujato)
- [SN45.155](https://suttacentral.net/sn45.155/en/sujato)
- [SN51.10](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.10/en/sujato)
- [SN51.11](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.11/en/sujato)
- [SN51.12](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.12/en/sujato)
- [SN51.13](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.13/en/sujato)
- [SN51.14](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.14/en/sujato)
- [SN51.15](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.15/en/sujato)
- [SN51.16](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.16/en/sujato)
- [SN51.17](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.17/en/sujato)
- [SN51.18](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.18/en/sujato)
- [SN51.19](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.19/en/sujato)
- [SN51.1](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.1/en/sujato)
- [SN51.20](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.20/en/sujato)
- [SN51.21](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.21/en/sujato)
- [SN51.22](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.22/en/sujato)
- [SN51.23](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.23/en/sujato)
- [SN51.24](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.24/en/sujato)
- [SN51.25](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.25/en/sujato)
- [SN51.26](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.26/en/sujato)
- [SN51.27](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.27/en/sujato)
- [SN51.28](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.28/en/sujato)
- [SN51.29](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.29/en/sujato)
- [SN51.2](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.2/en/sujato)
- [SN51.30](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.30/en/sujato)
- [SN51.31](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.31/en/sujato)
- [SN51.32](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.32/en/sujato)
- [SN51.33-44](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.33-44/en/sujato)
- [SN51.3](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.3/en/sujato)
- [SN51.4](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.4/en/sujato)
- [SN51.5](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.5/en/sujato)
- [SN51.6](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.6/en/sujato)
- [SN51.77-86](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.77-86/en/sujato)
- [SN51.7](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.7/en/sujato)
- [SN51.8](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.8/en/sujato)
- [SN51.9](https://suttacentral.net/sn51.9/en/sujato)
- [SN52.12](https://suttacentral.net/sn52.12/en/sujato)
- [SN5.5](https://suttacentral.net/sn5.5/en/sujato)
- [SN6.14](https://suttacentral.net/sn6.14/en/sujato)
- [SN6.5](https://suttacentral.net/sn6.5/en/sujato)
- [SN6.6](https://suttacentral.net/sn6.6/en/sujato)
- [SN8.10](https://suttacentral.net/sn8.10/en/sujato)
- [SN8.12](https://suttacentral.net/sn8.12/en/sujato)
- [Thag10.7](https://suttacentral.net/thag10.7/en/sujato)
- [Thag1.38](https://suttacentral.net/thag1.38/en/sujato)
- [Thag16.9](https://suttacentral.net/thag16.9/en/sujato)
- [Thag17.2](https://suttacentral.net/thag17.2/en/sujato)
- [Thag18.1](https://suttacentral.net/thag18.1/en/sujato)
- [Thag19.1](https://suttacentral.net/thag19.1/en/sujato)
- [Thag20.1](https://suttacentral.net/thag20.1/en/sujato)
- [Thag21.1](https://suttacentral.net/thag21.1/en/sujato)
- [Thag6.10](https://suttacentral.net/thag6.10/en/sujato)
- [Thag6.1](https://suttacentral.net/thag6.1/en/sujato)
- [Thig11.1](https://suttacentral.net/thig11.1/en/sujato)
- [Thig13.5](https://suttacentral.net/thig13.5/en/sujato)
- [Thig5.1](https://suttacentral.net/thig5.1/en/sujato)

Comment: @ruben2020 thank you. 

Answer (score 1):

[MN77](https://suttacentral.net/mn77/en/sujato#mn77:31.1) also discuss psychic powerin detail.

But if you want list of suttas containing psychic powers then try searching 'psychic power' in [Suttacentral Voice Search](http://voice.suttacentral.net) or simply  [click here](https://voice.suttacentral.net/scv/index.html?r=0.7488195714395707#/?search=psychic%20power).

You will also find 'settings' icon there where you can manage number of result you want to see.